# Action buttons only visible to admin yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I tried to add extra action buttons. Admin only view this button after button click update in a single field in the database.

```
  <p>
   <?php

    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest ){
      echo Html::a('Recommended', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
    echo  Html::a('Not Recommended', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to reject this application?',
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ]);
  } else if(Yii::$app->user->can('admin')){

  }
    ?>

</p>
```

My problem is that I have 3 users that are: *applicant*, *faculty* and *admin* (or hod). In this case after faculty recommendation, the admin (or hod) sanctioned the leave.

I create leave application and faculty recommended, so now I want get the recommended data when admin login to the site.

Comment: Are you using RBAC? If not, how do you identify your admin?

Comment: How you identify admin?

Comment: what change i made give a brief description about this

Comment: I have posted an answer i hope is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If admin is the username you should follow this way :

```
<p>
   <?php

    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest ){
      echo Html::a('Recommended', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], 
                  ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
      echo Html::a('Not Recommended', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to reject this application?',
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ]);
  } else if(Yii::$app->user->identity->username == 'admin' ){
      echo Html::a('Your Button Label for Admin',
           ['yourActionForAdmin', 'id' => $model->id], 
           ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
  }
    ?>

</p>
```

Comment: sir i have a doubt . can i put some conditions for getting different output in my same active view for different users.if it is possible where i put this conditions

Comment: Normally if the different output is related to the processi logic the better palace is the  action (in controller) if otherwise the different output is related to the aspect you shold do this in the view .. .. Anyway You can post a new separate question for  this explain  with a sampe what you need..